# gcc precompiled headers weird behaviour with -c option

Tags: c++, gcc, precompiled-headers

Short story:

I can't make precompiled headers work properly with gcc -c option.

Long story:

Folks, I'm using gcc-4.4.1 on Linux and before trying precompiled headers in a really large project I decided to test them on simple program. They "kinda work" but I'm not happy with results and I'm sure there is something wrong about my setup.

First of all, I wrote a simple program(main.cpp) to test if they work at all:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Then I created the precompiled headers file pre.h(in the same directory) as follows:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
```

...and compiled it:

```
$ g++ -I. pre.h
```

(pre.h.gch was created)

After that I measured compile time with and without precompiled headers:

**with pch**

```
$ time g++ -I. -include pre.h main.cpp

real    0m0.128s
user    0m0.088s
sys  0m0.048s
```

**without pch**

```
$ time g++ -I. main.cpp 

real    0m0.838s
user    0m0.784s
sys  0m0.056s
```

So far so good! **Almost 7 times faster, that's impressive!** Now let's try something more realistic. All my sources are built with -c option and for some reason I can't make pch play nicely with it. You can reproduce this with the following steps below...

I created the test module foo.cpp as follows:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

int whatever()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Here are the timings of my attempts to build the module foo.cpp with and without pch:

**with pch**

```
$ time g++ -I. -include pre.h -c foo.cpp 

real    0m0.357s
user    0m0.348s
sys 0m0.012s
```

**without pch**

```
$ time g++ -I. -c foo.cpp 

real    0m0.330s
user    0m0.292s
sys 0m0.044s
```

That's quite strange, looks like there is no speed up at all!(I ran timings for several times). It turned out precompiled headers were not used at all in this case, I checked it with -H option(output of "g++ -I. -include pre.h -c foo.cpp -H" didn't list pre.h.gch at all).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I think I've found the solution: **-fpch-preprocess** should be used alongside with **-c** option. It works like a charm!

Here's the timings:

**with pch**

```
$ time g++ -I. -include pre.h -c foo.cpp -fpch-preprocess

real    0m0.028s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.016s
```

**without pch**

```
$ time g++ -I. -c foo.cpp 

real    0m0.330s
user    0m0.292s
sys 0m0.044s
```

**Update:** I asked the same question on the gcc help mailing list and Ian Lance Taylor explained this strange behavior by my usage of distcc/ccache. These tools first preprocess the source that's why this options is required.