# Can precompiled headers be made to work with distcc?

Tags: gcc, precompiled-headers, distcc

I have a large project for which I've implemented precompiled headers. I'd also like to be able to get it to work with distcc. According to section 4.12 in the google code paper [here](http://distcc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/web/distcc-lca-2004.html)

> gcc version 3.3 includes some performance improvements that make distcc less immediately useful.
>
> One is precompiled headers, whereby the internal state of the compiler is dumped out to disk after reading a set of common header files. This is useful for programs that include a large and fixed set of headers, where parsing the headers takes a large fraction of the compile time. At the moment distcc can support this by putting the .pch state file on a shared filesystem. A better solution may be added to distcc in the future.

I don't think using a shared filesystem is a good solution for me. But there are also later mentions of a potential patch to get precompiled headers and distcc working together in a better way: https://lists.samba.org/archive/distcc/2008q2/003646.html. This would involve setting `DISTCC_PCH` on the client (or using the compiler option `-fpch-preprocess`, see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.1/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html)), and adding the `pch` option to the `DISTCC_HOSTS` for the servers. I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work so I suspect the patch wasn't integrated.

Is there any support for precompiled headers in distcc over and above a shared file system? Or any reasonably straightforward way of getting the technologies to cooperate?

---

Update: I now have a situation where I use precompiled headers compilation for a local build and for a distcc build I force include the precompiled header files so that local and distcc builds both compile exactly the same source. With a careful choice of precompiled headers I can get a local debug build to be about 40% faster than it was before and a distcc build is only about 4% slower. What I'd like it to somehow marry precompiled headers and distcc to get a speedup, say 10 or 20%, with distcc builds, with a fairly small amount of effort and intrusiveness (speeding up builds is not my primary responsibility and besides in a corporate environment I'm limited in what I can do).

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530864/gcc-precompiled-headers-weird-behaviour-with-c-option

Comment: The patch from http://lists.samba.org/archive/distcc/attachments/20080604/caa48a15/distcc-2.18.3-pch.diff-0001.obj - https://lists.samba.org/archive/distcc/2008q2/003646.html was not integrated. There was "src/pch.h" in the patch and there is no pch in recent distcc: https://github.com/distcc/distcc/tree/master/src the only word pch in distcc is web/distcc-lca-2004.html " At the moment distcc can support this by putting the `.pch` state file on a shared filesystem." Check also https://lists.samba.org/archive/distcc/2009q1/003895.html  "Precompiled headers support status" 2009.

Comment: Apple had some kind of precompiled headers integration in their fork of older distcc 2.18: https://opensource.apple.com/source/distcc/distcc-2805/distcc.README "As of 3.1.2, Xcode bundles a fork of an older version of distcc, 2.18.5-Apple.1. Apple distcc has several changes ... precompiled header support"

Comment: Nowadays distcc nodes can themselves compile the headers. So not exactly precompiled, but the load can be spread out on more nodes. They call it *pump* mode.